# JUnit max/min values

Tags: java, testing, junit

How would I test Bigdecimal max value from the Map values?

I have initially used Object mapper to map Strings.

Strings contained date and rate for the specific currency.

I would like to create a method that tests for max/min values.

it would be great to know the approach to test a LocalDate.

```
Map.Entry<LocalDate, BigDecimal> getMinRate(Response response) {
        return Collections.min(response.getBpi().entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
    }
```

Comment: question in 1 sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I get your question correct:

**ResponseUtilTest.class**

```
import org.junit.Test;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class ResponseUtilTest {

    @Test
    public void bigDecimalIsMinimumAndLocalDateAreValid() {
        ResponseUtil responseUtil = new ResponseUtil();
        Map<LocalDate, BigDecimal> bpi = new HashMap<>();
        bpi.put(LocalDate.of(2018, 10, 23), BigDecimal.valueOf(10));
        bpi.put(LocalDate.of(2018, 10, 22), BigDecimal.valueOf(20));
        bpi.put(LocalDate.of(2018, 10, 21), BigDecimal.valueOf(30));

        Map.Entry<LocalDate, BigDecimal> minRate = responseUtil.getMinRate(new Response(bpi));

        assertEquals(LocalDate.of(2018, 10, 23), minRate.getKey());
        assertEquals(BigDecimal.valueOf(10), minRate.getValue());
    }
}
```

**ResponseUtil.class**

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;

public class ResponseUtil {
    Map.Entry<LocalDate, BigDecimal> getMinRate(Response response) {
        return Collections.min(response.getBpi().entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: that looks great and clear, the only problem here is me not coming in with the answer myself :( alright, we all learning so now I have an example and i can take it from there, one question -> what if I want to test just a BigDecimal ? would i just simply remove assert equals ? 

probably a better choice to test them separately, however, I guess is depending on the logic  @i.bondarenko

Comment: Sure, you can remove LocalDate assert and leave only `assertEquals(BigDecimal.valueOf(10), minRate.getValue());`. Also you should rename the test method to `void bigDecimalIsMinimum()`

Comment: Dude thank you, I feel more comfortable in writing tests now, thank you so much and I do apologize for unclear description

Comment: No probs, glad to help you! If you are fine with the answer, mark it as solution, please :)

Comment: Would you mind telling me what import is  ResponseUtil class, and if you can shortly explain what it does, thank you

Comment: Sure, have a look at the adapted answer, please. I use only java.base library. If you wish we can continue in chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199849/discussion-between-tim-prozorov-and-i-bondarenko).